# Store UTC date time in database

Tags: php, mysql, datetime, utc

I will convert all date & time input by user (local time) to UTC and store it in database. When display back I will convert UTC time to their time zone which is set in their profile. Is it good?

Comment: @Mark Ransom: Why not post this as a proper answer so that the question can be closed?

Comment: @Ates, a proper answer would need some justification and caveats that I'm unprepared to provide. I just couldn't resist the opening that was given.

Comment: @Mark Ransom: It was an opening well taken sir :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think it's good enough. Besides storing user timezone in profile, you can also let client (for example, javascript) convert UTC time according to user computer time zone.

Answer (score 1):

As long as you can convert to/from any time zone from your stored DB records, that's all you need.

What you've described will work.

Answer (score 1):

Note some [MySQL documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/time-zone-support.html) in regards to timezone & server/client workings:

> Per-connection time zones.
>   Each client that connects has its own time zone setting, given by the session time_zone variable. Initially, the session variable takes its value from the global time_zone variable, but the client can change its own time zone with this statement:
>   mysql> SET time_zone = timezone;

So, normally, in your proposed solution, all is right, but don't let the actual server or client timezone changing catch you of guard.